# Request goes in timeout on MassTransit Test

Tags: c#, testing, request, masstransit

I need to test my API. I already see that it works, but during the test's part I have this problem: in my test's method I send a command with MediatR library. It reaches the Handler's phase and it sends a Request but it never gets a response.

This is my TestClass:

```
[TestClass]
    public class UnbindVisilibityTests : InfrastructureDataTestBase
    {
        private readonly InfrastructureDataTestDal _infrastructureDal = new InfrastructureDataTestDal();
        private ITestHarness _harness;
        private ServiceProvider _provider;

        UnbindVisibilityCommand command;

        int idVis;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void Init()
        {
            _provider = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddMassTransitTestHarness(cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.AddConsumer<UnbindUsersFromVisibilityFilterRequestConsumer>();
                    cfg.AddHandler<UnbindVisibilityCommand>(context => context.RespondAsync(true));
                })
                .BuildServiceProvider(true);

            _harness = _provider.GetRequiredService<ITestHarness>();

            idVis = _infrastructureDal.InsertVisibility("UnbindVisibilityCommandTest", "TestAppl");

            command = new UnbindVisibilityCommand
            {
                Id = idVis,
            };
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public async Task Unbind_OK()
        {
            await _harness.Start();

            var result = Mediator.Send(command).Result;

            Assert.IsTrue(result is SuccessCommandResult);

            await _harness.Stop();
        }

        [TestCleanup]
        public void CleanUpTest()
        {
            _infrastructureDal.DeleteVisibility(new int[] { idVis });
        }
    }
```

while this is my Handler's code:

```
public class UnbindVisibilityCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<UnbindVisibilityCommand, CommandResult>
    {
        private readonly IClientFactory _clientFactory;

        public UnbindVisibilityCommandHandler(IClientFactory clientFactory)
        {
            _clientFactory = clientFactory;
        }

        public async Task<CommandResult> Handle(UnbindVisibilityCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var client = _clientFactory.CreateRequestClient<IUnbindUsersFromVisibilityFilterRequest>();

            var response = await client.GetResponse<IUnbindUsersFromVisibilityFilterResult>(
            new
            {
                Id = request.Id
            });

            return new SuccessCommandResult();
        }
    }
```

and finally this is my Consumer's code:

```
public class UnbindUsersFromVisibilityFilterRequestConsumer : IConsumer<IUnbindUsersFromVisibilityFilterRequest>
    {
        private readonly IApplicativeUsersCommandDal _dal;

        public UnbindUsersFromVisibilityFilterRequestConsumer(IApplicativeUsersCommandDal dal)
        {
            _dal = dal;
        }

        public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IUnbindUsersFromVisibilityFilterRequest> context)
        {
            await _dal.UnbindUsersFromVisibilityAsync(context.Message.Id);

            await context.RespondAsync<IUnbindUsersFromVisibilityFilterResult>(new { });
        }
    }
```

This is the configuration of my test part:

```
public abstract class InfrastructureDataTestBase : TestBase
    {
        internal static IMediator Mediator;
        protected IServiceProvider serviceProvider;
        static bool _isInitialized;
        public IConfiguration configuration;

        public InfrastructureDataTestBase()
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                  .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + ".\\InfrastructureData.Tests")
                  .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                  .AddJsonFile("TokenVerificationSettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                  .AddEnvironmentVariables();

            configuration = builder.Build();

            if (_isInitialized == false)
            {
                serviceProvider = GetServiceProvider(configuration);

                Mediator = serviceProvider.GetService<IMediator>();
            }
        }

        public IServiceProvider GetServiceProvider(IConfiguration config)
        {
            ServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();

            services.AddControllers();

            DbProviderFactories.RegisterFactory("System.Data.SqlClient", SqlClientFactory.Instance);

            services.AddSwaggerApiVersioning<ConfigureSwaggerOptions>();

            var connProvider = ConnectionStringProviderFactory.CreateInstance(config.GetValue<string>("ConnectionStringFullFilePath"), config.GetValue<string>("RsaKeyFullFilePath"));

            services.AddSingleton(connProvider);

            services.AddLogging();

            services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(config);

            services.AddPagingProvider();

            services.AddHealthChecks();

            services.AddOptions(config);

            services.AddAccessTokenValidation();

            services.AddIdentityProvider(configuration.GetValue<string>("IDP.BaseUri"));

            services.AddApplicationLayer();

            services.AddDataInfrastructureLayer(configuration, connProvider);

            ConfigureServices(services, configuration);

            MessageBrokerOptions messageBrokerOptions = new();

            configuration.GetSection(MessageBrokerOptions.SectionName).Bind(messageBrokerOptions);

            services.AddMassTransit(x =>
            {                x.AddConsumer<UnbindUsersFromVisibilityFilterRequestConsumer>();

                x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
                {
                    cfg.Host(messageBrokerOptions.HostName, (ushort)messageBrokerOptions.Port, messageBrokerOptions.VirtualHost, h =>
                    {
                        var rsaFile = config.GetValue<string>("RsaKeyFullFilePath");

                        var cryptoService = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rsaFile)
                            ? Digitronica.IT.Infrastructure.Security.Cryptography.CryptoService.CreateDefault()
                            : Digitronica.IT.Infrastructure.Security.Cryptography.CryptoService.CreateFromXmlFile(rsaFile);

                        h.Username(messageBrokerOptions.Username);
                        h.Password(cryptoService.Decrypt(messageBrokerOptions.Password));
                    });

                    cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                });

                x.AddRequestClient<IUnbindUsersFromVisibilityFilterRequest>();
            });

            _isInitialized = true;

            return services.BuildServiceProvider();
        }
    }
```

Where the TestBase class is:

```
public abstract class TestBase
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)
        {
            services.AddControllers();

            DbProviderFactories.RegisterFactory("System.Data.SqlClient", SqlClientFactory.Instance);

            services.AddSwaggerApiVersioning<ConfigureSwaggerOptions>();

            services.AddConnectionStringProvider(config.GetValue<string>("ConnectionStringFullFilePath"), config.GetValue<string>("RsaKeyFullFilePath"));

            services.AddLogging();

            services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(config);

            services.AddPagingProvider();

            services.AddHealthChecks();

            services.AddOptions(config);

            services.AddAccessTokenValidation();
        }
    }
```

Comment: There isn't enough information to answer this question, unfortunately.

Comment: Which informations do you need? I edit the question with the configuration in addition if it can help

Comment: With debugging I saw that the request reaches the consumer. But when it tries to respond it seems that it doesn't find the return address